# Visual Studio asks credentials to Azure Storage

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 SP 1 and want to connect to the Azure Storage (different than I logged to Visual Studio account). Problem is I always have to check authentification even I set checkbox "I sign in frequently on this device. Don't ask me for a code"

[image]

How to solve it (tell to Visual Studio that I don't need auth via phone each time)?